# Bootstrap/jQuery modal not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following page:

http://www.poker-labs.com/571010001-1050-Super-Tuesday-300K-Gtd.html

As you can see, for some reason the modal is launched initially although I have defined `show: false`, also, the 'x' button should be working but it's not.

I feel like I'm missing something pretty basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added

```
$(".modal").modal("hide");
```

To your page?
Also, add:

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
```

To your div tag where you declare the modal

Comment: Why do I have to use the ``$(".modal").modal("hide");`` instead I'm using ``$('#remindme').modal({
            keyboard: true,
            show: false
        });``

Comment: I have followed what you've said, and it works now, but now when you click 'Launch Modal' (bottom of the page) it shows it and immediately after hides it.

Comment: nevermind, works. I added a function that uses ``$('#remindme').modal('show')``